# Show Hide rows in asp repeater within Listview - Only hiding first column

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview, asprepeater

I have the following ListView containing a repeater. The repeater loads three lists which act as the columns, each of the three lists contain another list which acts as the rows.

The below works but only hides the Description and the first value column. I need to be able to hide the description and all three value columns

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1"
        runat="server" DataKeyNames="KeyName1">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></div>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="div1" runat="server" class="col">
                <h2>
                    <asp:Label runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("ds1") %>' /></h2>
                <div class="premium">
                    <p>Monthly premium:</p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="Server" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <ul id="List1">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("Description")%>' />
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="Server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>' />
                                    </p>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
                <div class="reveal">
                    <p><a id="show" href="javascript:show();">Show</a><a id="hide" href="javascript:hide();" style="display:none;">hides</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

I have the following Javascript to show and hide the columns

```
window.onload = function () {
    hide();
};

function show() {
    var list = document.getElementById('List1').getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i >= 5) {
            list[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';
}

function hide() {
    var list = document.getElementById('List1').getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i >= 5) {
            list[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not using :

$("ul li").each (function(){

$(this).hide()

});

Comment: @wizexpert Thanks for your help. I'm new to javascript, where would I put this?

Comment: should be in your hide like this :
function hide() {
$("ul li").each (function(){ $(this).hide() });}

Comment: That's brilliant, many thanks the whole grid is not showing and hiding. However I I want to always show the first 5 rows and show and hide the rest?

Comment: try this"
function hide() { $("ul li").each (function(){ 
cnt =0
while (cnt<=5)
{
$(this).hide()
cnt++
}
 });}

Comment: Unfortunately I think that loop will complete through on each iteration of ".each". Is there a way of knowing which iteration of each it's on?

Comment: function hide() { $("ul li").each (function(){ cnt =0 while (cnt<=5) {
if(cnt>=5)
return false;
else
 $(this).hide() cnt++ } });}

Comment: Sorry but I can't get it to work, I think it's the same problem as mentioned above :(

Comment: here, I just went to my visual studio and tried this and it works,
function hide()

 {
var cnt =0; 
 $("ul li").each (function()
{
if(cnt==5)
{
return false;
}
else
{
 $(this).hide();
 cnt++;
 }
 

});

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to wizpert's advise I got it working with the below code :-)

```
function hide() {
    var cnt = 0;
    $("ul li").each(function () {
        if ((cnt > 9 && cnt < 16) || (cnt > 20 && cnt < 27) || (cnt > 31 && cnt < 38)) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        cnt++;
    });
}
```

I'm sure there are better solutions out there as if more data is loaded into the repeater or more ul li tags are added to the page the script will break :-)